# Ler dados de arquivo txt java e realizar operações em Java

Tags: java, arquivo, txt

Estou fazendo uma locadora de veículos em java preciso ler de um txt o tipo de cliente(char) , um intervalo de datas(string) e a quantidade de passageiros(int).

Preciso trazer esses dados para serem analisados , por exemplo de acordo com a qtd de passageiros faço cálculos de qual carro é mais adequado e de acordo com o tipo do cliente faço o calculo das taxas, de acordo com o dia da semana tem valores diferentes.

Mas eu não sei e não achei nenhum explicação plausível de como faço essa atrelamento das variáveis do arquivo para as variáveis corretas no código alguém pode me ajudar?

Metodo que le o arquivo:

```
private static void ler() {
            File dir = new File("C:\\Arquivos");
            File arq = new File(dir, "LocadoraCarro.txt");

            try {
                FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(arq);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
                String linha = "";
                while ( ( linha = bufferedReader.readLine() ) != null) {
                System.out.println(linha);
            }

                fileReader.close();
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

**Formato do Arquivo** :
    TIPO_DO_CLIENTE: QUANTIDADE_PASSAGEIROS: DATA1, DATA2, DATA3

**Exemplo**:
Normal: 2: 12Abr2018 (seg), 13Abr2018(ter)

Comment: Tem duas duvidas diferentes ai, sugiro que separe e deixe apenas uma, que é a leitura do txt.

Comment: E você fala de um arquivo txt mas nao mostra nenhum demonstrativo de linhas deste arquivo. Edite a pergunta e adicione algumas linhas deste arquivo para facilitar o entendimento.

Comment: @Articuno feita as alterações solicitadas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso é bem tranquilo de fazer, o que deve estar de atrapalhando é a forma como você ta olhando o problema.

Primeiro utilizei uma classe para representar o dado, chamei de `Data`. Essa classe não tem nada demais. Apenas alguns atributos, setters, getters e uma implementação do método `toString()`.

E os métodos `getClientType(String[] split)`, `getNPassengers(String[] split)` e 
`parseDates(String[] split)` recuperam cada atributo da classe `Data` dado uma linha do arquivo.

No método `readFile(String filePath)`, a cada linha lida do arquivo uma nova instancia da classe Data é criada e adicionada a uma lista.
Cada elemento dessa lista representa uma linha do arquivo de entrada.

Classe completa:

```
public class Main {

    private static class Data{
        private String clientType;
        private int nPassagers;
        private String[] dates;

        public Data(String clientType, int nPassagers, String[] dates) {
            this.clientType = clientType;
            this.nPassagers = nPassagers;
            this.dates = dates;
        }

        public String getClientType() {
            return clientType;
        }

        public void setClientType(String clientType) {
            this.clientType = clientType;
        }

        public int getnPassagers() {
            return nPassagers;
        }

        public void setnPassagers(int nPassagers) {
            this.nPassagers = nPassagers;
        }

        public String[] getDates() {
            return dates;
        }

        public void setDates(String[] dates) {
            this.dates = dates;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Data{" +
                    "clientType='" + clientType + '\'' +
                    ", nPassagers=" + nPassagers +
                    ", dates=" + Arrays.toString(dates) +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    private static List<Data> readFile(String filePath){
        File arq = new File(filePath);

        List<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(arq);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            String linha = "";
            while ((linha = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] split = linha.split(":");
                dataList.add(new Data(getClientType(split), getNPassengers(split), parseDates(split)));
            }

            fileReader.close();
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return dataList;
    }

    private static String getClientType(String[] split){
        if (split == null || split.length == 0){
            return null;
        }

        return split[0];
    }

    private static int getNPassengers(String[] split){
        if (split == null || split.length < 2 || split[1] == null){
            return -1;
        }

        return Integer.valueOf(split[1].trim());
    }

    private static String[] parseDates(String[] split){
        if (split == null || split.length < 3 || split[2] == null){
            return null;
        }

        return split[2].trim().split(",");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<Data> result = readFile("LocadoraCarro.txt");

        for (Data data : result){
            System.out.println(data.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro, não sei bem qual seu objetivo ao usar um arquivo TXT, mas o ideal nessa situação é usar um banco de dados, que já dispõe de todo o mecanismo para tratar os dados.

Mas como o seu caso é um TXT, não tem problema! Assim como em uma aplicação que usa um banco de dados, usaremos a orientação à objetos para representar os dados no nosso programa.

Para isso, sugiro que pesquise um pouco sobre a orientação à objetos, por hora explicarei o básico para que você possa dar continuidade depois...

Para representar os dados do seu txt, criaremos uma classe contendo os respectivos atributos que você quer recuperar do txt

package br.com.cogerh.template.model;

import java.util.List;

public class Arquivo {

```
//ESSE ATRIBUTO IRÁ REPRESENTAR UM CLIENTE
private String cliente;

//LISTA COM TODAS AS DATAS
private List<String> data;

//QUANTIDADE DE PASSAGEIROS
private Integer qtdPassageiros;

public Arquivo(){

}


public Arquivo(String cliente, List<String> data, Integer qtdPassageiros) {
    super();
    this.cliente = cliente;
    this.data = data;
    this.qtdPassageiros = qtdPassageiros;
}

public void implementacaoMetodo1(){
    System.out.println("EXEMPLO DE IMPLEMENTACAO DO METODO 1");
}

public void implementacaoMetodo2(){
    System.out.println("EXEMPLO DE IMPLEMENTACAO DO METODO 2");

}


public String getCliente() {
    return cliente;
}

public void setCliente(String cliente) {
    this.cliente = cliente;
}

public List<String> getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(List<String> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public Integer getQtdPassageiros() {
    return qtdPassageiros;
}

public void setQtdPassageiros(Integer qtdPassageiros) {
    this.qtdPassageiros = qtdPassageiros;
}
```

}

Feito isso, temos nossa classe representa os clientes! Nessa classe também temos  exemplos de métodos que servirá para você implementar suas regras de cálculos de taxas e etc...

O próximo passo é chamar da classe que ler o txt a Classe cliente que acabamos de criar e passar os valores por meio do construtor da classe ou os métodos set dos atributos.