# Ler um arquivo txt a partir de um layout determinado

Tags: java

Estou precisando ler um arquivo `txt` que tem vários valores.

Exemplo:

```
41976127992Jhonatan   3129176513
```

Só que quero pegar somente partes destes valores me baseando num layout, por exemplo:

```
CPF = Posição 1 a 11
Nome = Posição 12 a 22 ( neste caso tem espaços no arquivo ) 
Agencia = Posição 23 a 26
Conta = Posição 27a 32
```

E gostaria de gravar estes valores em uma variável, posteriormente vou pegar essa variável e comparar com outra variável.

Comment: Relacionada (ou duplicata): [Ler dados de arquivo txt java e realizar operações em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/277057/28595)

Comment: Somente ler um arquivo eu já achei por aqui, mas realizar a leitura se baseando por posições eu não achei, por isso este caso não se trata de uma pergunta duplicada, eu já cassei na net isso mas não achei, por isso resolvi criar uma conta e perguntar, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Você não precisa ler cada trecho separado, baseando-se nas posições. Uma abordagem mais fácil é simplesmente ler a linha toda e em seguida usar [`substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) para obter cada trecho da linha separadamente:

```
String nomeArquivo = "arquivo.txt";
try (BufferedReader br =
         new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(nomeArquivo), "UTF-8"))) {
    String linha; // para cada linha
    while ((linha = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String cpf = linha.substring(0, 11);
        String nome = linha.substring(11, 22);
        String agencia = linha.substring(22, 26);
        String conta = linha.substring(26);
        System.out.printf("CPF=%s, nome=%s, agencia=%s, conta=%s\n", cpf, nome, agencia, conta);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // trate o erro como achar melhor
}
```

Note que usei a sintaxe de [*try-with-resources*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), que garante que o arquivo será fechado ao final da execução. Ainda sim foi preciso um `catch`, pois o `FileInputStream` pode lançar uma exceção se o arquivo não existir, o `readLine()` pode lançar outra se ocorrer algum erro durante a leitura, etc.

Com isso eu uso `readLine()` para ler a linha inteira do arquivo, e depois uso `substring` para obter os trechos que me interessam. Nos 3 primeiros casos, usa-se o índice inicial e final, sendo que a `String` começa sempre no índice zero, e o índice final não é incluído.

Por exemplo, `substring(0, 11)` pega dos índices zero a 10 (ou seja, os 11 primeiros caracteres, que no caso correspondem aos dígitos do CPF). Já no último caso, eu coloquei apenas o índice inicial (26), e neste caso `substring` pega tudo desde este índice até o final da `String`.

Eu também setei o *encoding* do arquivo como UTF-8, mas você pode mudar para o *encoding* que o seu arquivo estiver usando. A saída é:

```
CPF=41976127992, nome=Jhonatan   , agencia=3129, conta=176513
```

---

A partir do Java 8 também é possível usar *streams*:

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(nomeArquivo), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
    stream.forEach(linha -> {
        String cpf = linha.substring(0, 11);
        String nome = linha.substring(11, 22);
        String agencia = linha.substring(22, 26);
        String conta = linha.substring(26);
        System.out.printf("CPF=%s, nome=%s, agencia=%s, conta=%s\n", cpf, nome, agencia, conta);
    });
} catch (IOException e) {
    // trate o erro como achar melhor
}
```

---

Com base [no seu comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/359890/ler-um-arquivo-txt-a-partir-de-um-layout-determinado/359996?noredirect=1#comment719676_359996), se cada linha tem uma informação diferente, basta manter um contador de linhas, e de acordo com o número da linha, ler as respectivas informações. Exemplo:

```
try (BufferedReader br = ...) {
    String linha; // para cada linha
    int numeroLinha = 0; // em qual linha estou
    while ((linha = br.readLine()) != null) {
        numeroLinha++; // atualiza número da linha
        switch (numeroLinha % 2) {
            case 1: // primeira linha
                String cpf = linha.substring(0, 11);
                String nome = linha.substring(11, 22);
                String agencia = linha.substring(22, 26);
                String conta = linha.substring(26);
                System.out.printf("CPF=%s, nome=%s, agencia=%s, conta=%s\n", cpf, nome, agencia, conta);
                break;
            case 0: // segunda linha
                // ler endereço
                break;
        }
    }
```

No caso, estou assumindo que o arquivo tem uma linha com CPF/Nome/etc e outra com endereço, depois outra com CPF/Nome/etc e outra com endereço e assim por diante. Por isso usei `numeroLinha % 2` (o resto da divisão do número da linha por 2). Quando o resto da divisão for 1, estou em uma linha ímpar, e portanto é uma linha que contém o CPF/Nome/etc. Quando o resto for zero, estou em uma linha par, e portanto é o endereço.

Adapte o código para o formato do seu arquivo. Se tiver mais tipos de linhas diferentes, basta atualizar os valores. Por exemplo, se for a primeira linha com nome/CPF, a segunda com endereço, a terceira com telefone, a quarta com cartão de crédito, basta fazer algo do tipo:

```
while ((linha = br.readLine()) != null) {
    numeroLinha++; // atualiza número da linha
    switch (numeroLinha % 4) {
        case 1: // primeira linha
            // ler nome/CPF
            break;
        case 2: // segunda linha
            // ler endereço
            break;
        case 3: // terceira linha
            // ler telefone
            break;
        case 0: // quarta linha
            // ler cartão de crédito
            break;
    }
```

E assim por diante. Novamente, estou assumindo que o formato do seu arquivo segue esse padrão de sempre ter N linhas, cada uma com um tipo de informação, se repetindo sem quebras.

---

<sup>*Caso o formato seja outro, favor [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/359890/edit) a pergunta e atualizar as informações com o formato do arquivo.*</sup>

Comment: Seu código faz total sentido, consegui entender e refazê-lo aqui no eclipse, o que pega é: o arquivo tem um total de 31 posições em cada linha, só que a linha de baixo vão ter outras informações, não são as mesmas que a linha de cima, ai ele pega cpf/nome ... certo da primeira linha, mas da linha de baixo que por exemplo é toda reservada para o endereço com 30 posições, ele acaba, dando como nome/cpf o nome da rua e por ai vai ...

Comment: @JhonatanPratsBulgari Atualizei a resposta. Se o formato do arquivo for muito diferente do que eu assumi, por favor [edite a pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/359890/edit), colocando o formato exato do arquivo